# using .filter() in swift: error: cannot convert value of type '([V]) -> Bool' to expected argument type '([_]) -> Bool'

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to make a `Graph` class with an `outEdges` method (just for the purpose of learning Swift, not because I need a Graph class).

I thought I could use `.filter()` to implement the outEdges method, but I get this error:

```
error: cannot convert value of type '([V]) -> Bool' to expected argument type '([_]) -> Bool'
        return edges.filter(leftVertexIs(v))
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

With this code:

```
class Graph<V: Equatable> {
    var edges = [[V]]()

    func addEdge(v1: V, _ v2: V) -> Graph<V> {
        edges.append([v1, v2])
        return self
    }

    func leftVertexIs(v: V) -> (([V]) -> Bool) {
        return {(e: [V]) -> Bool in return e[0] == v}
    }

    func outEdges(v: V) -> [V] {
        return edges.filter(leftVertexIs(v))
    }
}

var g = Graph<Int>()
g.addEdge(2, 4).addEdge(4, 6).addEdge(3, 5).addEdge(2, 7)
g.outEdges(2)
```

(Note: I moved the filter predicate into a closure to ensure it was working properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edges` has the type `[[V]]`, then `edges.filter()`
has the same type and that should be the return type of `outEdges`:

```
func outEdges(v: V) -> [[V]] {
    return edges.filter(leftVertexIs(v))
}
```

*Remark:* Instead of storing each edge as a two-element array you should consider to use a tuple `(left : V , right : V)` or a `struct` instead.